# How to include OpenSans font locally in my MVC project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, svg, fonts

I was using the OpenSans font from google's CDN:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v6/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3T8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff) format('TrueType');
}
```

However this generates browser warnings when my site runs in SSL mode (mixing secure/non-secure content).

So I'd rather host the files locally in my application.

For the life of my I cannot get this to work. I can't find anyone on the internet where I can download the package of .woff / .eot / .svg / .ttf files. I found I could download the .ttf files from http://www.google.com/fonts   but have not managed to get this to work locally in my project & not sure the files are sufficient.

Is there some place these font packages can be downloaded from, and how can I integrate them into my project?

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question but for anyone looking.

You need to use "https" instead of "http" in all requests on the page. So where "**http**://themes.googleusercontent.com" is, it needs to be "**https**://themes.googleusercontent.com".

```
@font-face {
      font-family: 'Open Sans';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 400;
      src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(https://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v6/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3T8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff) format('TrueType');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Immediately found the answer. I can upload TTF files to this website to convert to webfonts:

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator